# Resource 'someid' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using graph v1 .net sdk to get directory information like me.Request()/applications.Request()

i will get following error

Code: Request_ResourceNotFound
Message: Resource 'a1705c9c-420e-4ced-9ee8-3e8e49bb4226' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.
Inner error:
AdditionalData:
date: 2020-09-14T18:53:03
request-id: 50526962-1eb4-4e54-8010-a277a67fcbdc
client-request-id: 50526962-1eb4-4e54-8010-a277a67fcbdc
ClientRequestId: 50526962-1eb4-4e54-8010-a277a67fcbdc

Below is my code

```
_confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
             .Create(clientId)
             .WithTenantId(tenantId)
             .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
             .Build();

ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(_confidentialClientApplication);                    
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

var directory = await graphClient.Directory.Request().GetAsync();
var me = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are obtaining a token via the confidential client flow, meaning you not running in the context of a user. Thus you should not be using the /me endpoint, but /users/objectID one.

Please refer to this [Github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-daemon-webapp) sample which may helps you.

Comment: thank you for this answer that helps to understand what the problem is in this scenario